# Progmatically binding the dropdownlist in edititem template in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to bind dropdownlist in Gridview under EditItemTemplate under RowBound event. But it gives me blank rows in the drop down list:Here is my Design

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' Width="400px"></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>'></asp:Label>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCities" runat="server" Width="400px"></asp:DropDownList>
   </EditItemTemplate>
   <FooterTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNewDescFooter" runat="server" Width="400px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCitiesFooter_SelectedIndexChanged">
      </asp:DropDownList>
   </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Now here is my Row DataBound Event:

```
protected void grdFerries_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
   {
       DropDownList ddlCities = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlCities");
       DataAccessClass DAC = new DataAccessClass();
       string Query = "select description from JoursFeries where Year(JoursFeries.date) >= Year(GETDATE()) order by date asc";
       DataTable dtddl = DAC.ReturnDatatablefromQuery(Query, DBConnectionString);
       ddlCities.DataSource = dtddl;
       ddlCities.DataTextField = "description";
       ddlCities.DataValueField = "description";
       ddlCities.DataBind();
       ddlCities.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
   }
}
```

I am getting blank Dropdownlist. pls help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the block of code you have written will never get executed. You need to check if the row is a `DataRow` and not the state. You will have to check whether the row being bounded is in edit mode or not. This should work for you:-

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && grdFerries.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex)
{
   DropDownList ddlCities = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlCities");
   DataAccessClass DAC = new DataAccessClass();
   ..and so on
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul, but still after editing the code as per your reply I have the same issue dropdownlist is blank. I have added the code in RowDataBound event of Gridview.

Comment: @Abhishek_Chourasia - Are you rebinding the gridview in `OnRowEditing ` event? Without that it will not work.

Comment: Yes Rahul, on Row Editing(grdFerries_RowEditing), I am rebinding the grid:
Code of Row Editing:
grdFerries.SelectedIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
FillDataGridView();

Comment: @Abhishek_Chourasia - Yeah so that's wrong, you need to set _EditIndex_ property of gridview and not _selectedIndex_. Please change your `Row Editing` event.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rahul, making change in the `Row Editing` Event did the trick for me. Thanks for your help. :)